# My texinfo isn't listed by info

Tags: info

The Emacs lisp introduction was [translated to Spanish](https://savannah.nongnu.org/git/?group=elisp-es) by volunteers. I write a [PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/elisp-es/) to "compile" the texinfo file and had the results installed on my system.

I did some changes to the original translation:

```
diff -c a/elisp-es-1e8e9d693256/emacs-lisp-intro-es.texi b/elisp-es-1e8e9d693256/emacs-lisp-intro-es.texi
--- a/elisp-es-1e8e9d693256/emacs-lisp-intro-es.texi    2015-12-12 23:55:13.000000000 -0600
+++ b/elisp-es-1e8e9d693256/emacs-lisp-intro-es.texi    2015-12-12 23:56:28.000000000 -0600
@@ -229,9 +229,7 @@
 @c @end direntry
 @dircategory Emacs
 @direntry
-* Emacs Lisp Intro: (eintr).
-       Una Introducción sencilla a la programación en 
-Emacs Lisp.
+* Introducción a Emacs lisp: (eintr-es).  Una Introducción sencilla a la programación en Emacs Lisp.
 @end direntry



Diff finished.  Sat Dec 12 23:56:52 2015
```

Thing is, `info` don't lists the new installed info document, I just see the original Emacs lisp introduction listed but not the translated file. I can read the installed file with `info eintr-es`, but, again, nothing about getting the file listed by info anywhere.